# How to get my navbar image to be responsive with my navbar

Tags: jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4

Currently when I am on desktop my navbar looks perfect. When I go to mobile my navbar image does not fit on my mobile navbar. For example here is a picture of what my image looks like and my hamburger menu is not there.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVOb3.png)

After I refresh my page here the hamburger menu shows

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJXPq.png)

Not sure if this a rails thing as well but I have to refresh my page to get my hamburger icon to show on my mobile navbar.

```
<header id="header-wrap">
  <!-- Navbar Start -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top scrolling-navbar">
    <%= link_to image_tag("logo2.png", alt: "Brand"), root_path, :class=>'navbar-brand' %>
    <div class="container">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-navbar" aria-controls="main-navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          <span class="lni-menu"></span>
          <span class="lni-menu"></span>
          <span class="lni-menu"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main-navbar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item dropdown active">
            <%= link_to 'Home', root_path, class: 'nav-link dropdown active' %>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <%= link_to 'Categories', categories_path, class: 'nav-link' %>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <%= link_to 'Business Directory', business_directory_path, class: 'nav-link dropdown-toggle' %>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <%= link_to 'Partners', partner_path, class: 'nav-link dropdown-toggle' %>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <%= link_to 'News & Tech', blogs_path, class: 'nav-link' %>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="sign-in">
          <% if user_signed_in? %>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <%= link_to 'My Account', edit_user_registration_path, :class => 'nav-link dropdown-toggle', 'aria-haspopup' => 'true', 'aria-expanded' => 'false' %>
              <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <%= link_to 'My Ads', myads_path, class: 'dropdown-item' %>
                <%= link_to 'Inbox', conversations_path, class: 'dropdown-item' %>
                <%= link_to 'Settings', edit_user_registration_path, class: 'dropdown-item' %>
                <%= link_to 'Logout', destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, :class => 'dropdown-item' %>
              </div>
            </li>
          <% else %>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <%= link_to 'Login / Signup', new_user_session_path, :class => 'nav-link dropdown-toggle' %>
          </li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
        <%= link_to 'Post Ad', new_post_path, :class => 'tg-btn' %>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Mobile Menu Start -->
    <ul class="mobile-menu">
      <li>
        <%= link_to 'Home', root_path, class: 'active' %>
      </li>
      <li>
        <%= link_to 'Catgeories', categories_path %>
      </li>
      <li>
        <%= link_to 'Business Directory', business_directory_path %>
      </li>
      <li>
        <%= link_to 'Partners', partner_path %>
      </li>
      <li>
        <%= link_to 'News & Tech', blogs_path %> 
      </li>
      <li>
        <%= link_to 'Post Ad', new_post_path %> 
      </li>
      <li>
        <% if user_signed_in? %>
        <%= link_to 'My Account', edit_user_registration_path %>
        <ul class="dropdown">
          <li><%= link_to 'My Account', edit_user_registration_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to 'My Ads', myads_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to 'Settings', edit_user_registration_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to 'Logout', destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %></li>
        </ul>
        <% else %>
        <%= link_to 'Login / Signup', new_user_registration_path %>
        <% end %>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <!-- Mobile Menu End -->

  </nav>
</header>
```

Here is my application.js file

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require jquery3
//= require popper
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require jquery.slick
//= require local-time
//= require summernote/summernote-bs4.min
//= require summernote-init
//= require social-share-button
//= require activestorage
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include an additional class with the navbar image to make it responsive. If you are using bootstrap 3, use .img-responsive, if it's bootstrap 4 use .img-fluid. Hope that helps!

Comment: unfortunately that didn't help